# Efficient multiple selects in a single stored proc

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, select

I need to create a stored proc that returns two result sets. The second set contains records that are related to the records in the first set through a parent/child relationship.

For example, the first statement returns orders:

```
SELECT ID, col2, col3, ...
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE x=y
```

the second statement returns individual items for these orders:

```
SELECT ID, OrderID, col3, col4, ...
FROM dbo.OrderItems
WHERE OrderID IN (<IDs from first statement>)
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way to achieve this. Currently my solution looks like this:

```
-- create a table variable to hold results from first statement
DECLARE @Result TABLE 
(
   ID int NOT NULL, 
   col2 nvarchar(50),
   col3 nvarchar(50)
)

-- select orders
INSERT INTO @Result (ID, col2, col3)
SELECT ID, col2, col3, ...
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE x=y

SELECT * FROM @Result 

-- select order items corresponding to the orders in the @Result table
SELECT ID, OrderID, col3, col4
FROM dbo.OrderItems I
INNER JOIN @Result R ON R.ID = I.OrderID
```

This seems to work quite well. However requirements are so that the WHERE clause in the first statement gets quite complex and lends itself to using a CTE (WITH statement), but having both a WITH and a table variable gets pretty convoluted. What is a better way to solve this?

Comment: I don't see any problem in combination of CTE and table-variable. We are using it and I didn't register any issue.

Comment: What about a single resultset?

Comment: @TcKs: I'm sure it would work, but I don't think it's very elegant. I will certainly use this if there are no better suggestions.

Comment: @gbn: The second result set contains different columns than the first. The two result sets are "assembled" into objects with the same parent/child relationship in the business layer. Using a single result set would entail returning lots of unnecessary empty fields, and more logic to map the right fields to object properties in the business tier.

Comment: There is no way how to resturn multiple result set via single SELECT statement. So you can do two SELECTs with similar JOINs/WHEREs over same tables or you must use tabler-variable/temporary-table. There is no silver-bullet solution, if you want best solution for your situation, you could try all ways with production data and measure performace (memory usage, time of select, table locks, etc...). However from my experience using table-variable is good solution in general.

Comment: @TcKs: I'm aware that I need more than one SELECT statement. I was hoping for a suggestion that is more elegant/efficient than what I have now, especially considering the WHERE clause that might get very complex (including several sub-selects etc.)

Comment: @matk: I meant using a JOIN, not a UNION...

Comment: @gbn: I'm not sure I understand your approach. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @matk: SELECT .. FROM dbo.Orders o JOIN dbo.OrderItems i ON O.ID = I.OrderID WHERE ...

Comment: @gbn: This SELECT statement will return a non-normalized flat table, which I don't think is suitable for the hierarchical data I'm dealing with here. You'd have to deal with a lot of duplicate data in the columns selected from the Orders table, since every order will have multiple OrderItems. This is what I meant with "unnecessary fields" above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way here will be to use a CTE(Common Table Expression).

Syntax for the same is

```
;With CTE as
(
   Select ...
)
```

Your Query should be like this...

```
;WITH @Result AS
(
   SELECT 
     ID, 
     col2, 
     col3, ...
   FROM 
    dbo.Orders
   WHERE x=y
)
SELECT 
  ID, 
  OrderID, 
  col3,
  col4
FROM 
  dbo.OrderItems I
INNER JOIN
  @Result
ON
  @Result.ID   = I.OrderID
ON
```